# How does typescript make an object's type the type of its current value?

Tags: typescript

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: '2' }
```

Then, the type of `obj` is:

```
{ a: number, b: string }
```

But sometimes, I hope that its type is:

```
{ a: 1, b: '2' }
```

In addition to the following：

```
const obj: { a: 1, b: '2' } = { a: 1, b: '2' }
```

Is there any other good way?

Comment: A value can't be assigned as a type, so there's no way to do this. What are you trying to achieve with the type assigned as the current value? Perhaps there's another way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve literal types when inferring the type of a constant you can use an `as const` assertion:

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: '2' } as const
// Same as
// const obj: {
//     readonly a: 1;
//     readonly b: "2";
// }
```

This will also make the object readonly but this is probably ok for a constant anyway.

If you don't want properties to be `readonly` there are several options, but none are necessarily seamless.

One option is to use `as const` on the literals:

```
const obj = { a: 1 as const, b: '2' as const } 
// Same as
// const obj: {
//     a: 1;
//     b: "2";
// }
```

Or declare the `readonly` version first and then make it mutable:

```
type Mutable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P]}
const ro_obj = { a: 1 , b: '2' } as const
const obj: Mutable<typeof ro_obj> = ro_obj
// const obj: {
//     a: 1;
//     b: "2";
// }
```

Or my personal favorite use a function instead to infer string literal types:

```
function asLiterals<T extends Record<string, string | number | null | undefined | boolean >>(o: T) {
  return o;
}
const obj = asLiterals({ a: 1 , b: '2' });
// Same as 
// const obj: {
//     a: number;
//     b: string;
// }
```

Comment: The const here is for example only. So can it be not readonly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enforce a type having a property `a` that always has a value of `1`, or more generally, enforce some properties' guaranteed constant value, have it satisfy an interface resembling this:

```
interface RedCircle extends Shape {
  type: "circle";
  color: "red";
}
```

Keep in mind that this only works with primitive values on the property, or object or array literals containing other literal values. Type inference may be limited here if the value is referenced only in variable form. Typescript can't always infer the value of a named thing. In instances like this, these type signatures chiefly serve as assertions, guaranteeing to the downstream code that a value should be considered a `RedCircle`.